# Returning multiple TYPES from a Function? What is the recommended approach?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a PoC in my free time in PL/PGSQL (PG 13.3) for the first time. I am slowly moving forward, but I now want to return a SETOF Person_Found (type) so that the caller can "SELECT * FROM find_person()" and see the list of people found and the corresponding columns, just like a standard select.
The TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE CONFIDENCE AS ENUM ('HIGHEST', 'HIGH', 'LOW');

CREATE TYPE PERSON_FOUND AS (
  person_id UUID,
  rank INT,
  confidence CONFIDENCE,
  last_update TIMESTAMPTZ
);
```

The FUNCTION:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_person_by_email(p_email TEXT,
                            p_names_rec RECORD,
                            p_phone TEXT,
                            p_document TEXT,
                            p_date_of_birth TIMESTAMPTZ)
RETURNS SETOF PERSON_FOUND AS $$                            
DECLARE  
-- Variables
BEGIN
  -- do the search here with different queries and tables and then COMBINE the result into PERSON_FOUND Types. 
  IF (conditions_satisfied) THEN
     --RETURN THE LIST OF PERSON_FOUND
  ELSE 
     RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As I am combining different queries and loops and other functions to create a LIST of PERSON_FOUND types to be returned, I am confused about the idiomatic way of building this in Pl/pgsql.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure you need to create a `type`. A generic `returns setof(table)` would seem to work. See [return types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-overview.html#PLPGSQL-ARGS-RESULTS) 43.1.2. Supported Argument and Result Data Types and follow the links here: "Specific examples appear in Section 43.3.1 and Section 43.6.1." for examples.

Comment: Please show a complete example including table description (ddl) , sample data, as text -, **no images -, and expected results. Even better build a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13) with table and inserted data.  Update the question. Do not just add a comment. Voting to close.